# Windows memory management and java

Tags: java, windows, memory-management

I'm running a Windows 2016 (x64) server with 32GB RAM. According to Resource Monitor the memory map looks like this:
1MB Reserved, 17376MB In Use, 96MB Modified, 4113MB Standby, 11016MB Free. Summary:
15280MB Available,
4210 MB Cached,
32767MB Total,
32768MB Installed

I have a java (64-bit JVM) service that I want to run on 8GB of memory:
`java -Xms8192m -Xmx8192m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=128m ...`

which results in

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
```

I know that 32-bit OS and 32-bit JVM would limit the usable heap, but I verified both are 64-bit. I read that on 32-bit windows / JVM, the heap has be be contiguous. But here I had hoped to be able to even allocate 15GB for the heap, as over 15GB are 'Available' (available for whom / what?).

Page file size is automatically managed, and currently at 7680MB.

I'd be thankful for an explanation why Windows refuses to hand out the memory (or why java cannot make use of it), and what are my options (apart from resizing the host or using like 4GB, which works but is insufficient for the service).

I have tried rebooting the server, but when it's this service's turn to start, other services have already "worked" the memory quite a bit.

Edit: I noticed that the Resource Monitor has a graph called 'Commit Charge' which is over 90%. Task manager has a 'Committed' line which (today) lists 32,9/40,6 GB. [Commit charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commit_charge) explains the term, and yes, I've seen the mentioned virtual memory popups already. It seems that for a reason unknown to me, a very high Commit Charge has built up and prevents the 8GB-java from starting. This puts even more emphasis on the question: What does '15 GB Available' memory mean - and to whom is it available, if not for a process?

Comment: Are you maybe using a 32-bit java version? Check the output of java -version

Comment: Thanks, I did check that and mentioned that I verified it. Also, when using 4GB, the JVM starts, which would not be possible in a 32-bit jvm.